# Disable a button with JSTL

Tags: jstl

How do I disable a submit button in JSTL if the text field is blank or empty?

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<input id="namebutton" type="submit" />
```

Comment: Which below code?

Comment: sorry. it was above code.